# Added PPA, can't get updated packages

Tags: drivers, apt, ati, updates, ppa

Alright, I'm no so much a ubuntu novice, but this one has me pulling my hair out.  I've done this a MILLION times before, but this time something is just not working.

I have added 2 PPA's:

```
ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

and BOTH show up in my software sources (source code is unchecked, like normal)

performed a `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install mesa` to get my latest AMD open-source drivers but... `E: unable to locate package mesa`

Here is the launchpad http for the package I want:

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers

I really have no idea what is going on this time over something so seemingly easy.

Running ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Oh, sorry 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to install `libg3dvl-mesa` and `mesa-vdpau-drivers` and not `mesa`, according to the launchpad documentation you pointed to. So after you do `sudo apt-get update` do:

```
sudo apt-get install libg3dvl-mesa
sudo apt-get install mesa-vdpau-drivers
```

Comment: I can't seem to pull in any package from this PPA... somehow I pulled in mesa-vdpau-drivers (but i think its an older source - like from ubuntu main).

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt: Are you sure you have added the ppa correctly? If yes, what is the output of `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` and `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers` and `sudo apt-get update` for the ppa? If it is a 404, there is something wrong.

Comment: it adds the ppa, asks me to press enter to add the PAA.  I did and its listed also in software sources.  no 404s